# Neo4J deep duplicated nodes

Tags: neo4j, duplicates

For the data (below), my query looks like that:

```
MATCH p = (ob:Obiect)<--(w:Word { value:'game' })-[*]-(x) RETURN {id: id(x), value: x.value}

CREATE (w0:Obiect { value : 'Obiect' })
CREATE (w1:Word { value:'game' })
CREATE (w2:Word { value:'unreal' })
CREATE (w3:Word { value:'a' })
CREATE (w4:Word { value:'b'})
CREATE (w5:Word { value:'c' })
CREATE (w6:Word { value:'d'})
CREATE (w1)-[:IS]->(w0)
CREATE (w2)-[:IS]->(w1)
CREATE (w3)-[:HAS]->(w2)
CREATE (w4)-[:HAS]->(w3)
CREATE (w5)-[:HAS]->(w4)
CREATE (w6)-[:HAS]->(w5)
CREATE (w6)-[:HAS]->(w3)
```

If the relation (value:d)-->(value:a) doesn't exist then it’s okay and my results looks like this:

```
id 4070    value unreal
id 4071    value a
id 4072    value b
id 4073    value c
id 4074    value d
```

but if the relation exists then i have duplicates nodes (below). The question is how to avoid this problem?

```
id 4063    value unreal
id 4064    value a
id 4065    value b
id 4066    value c
id 4067    value d
id 4064    value a
id 4067    value d
id 4066    value c
id 4065    value b
id 4064    value a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MERGE clause : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html

```
MERGE (w3:Word { value:'a' })
MERGE (w4:Word { value:'b'})
MERGE(w3)-[:HAS]->(w4)
```

MERGE acts as "MATCH or CREATE" .

Be aware that MERGE will attempt to match the entire pattern, which can be confusing the first times, so I recommend you this helpful article from Graphaware : http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/31/cypher-merge-explained.html